# iOS Interface Builder - How to reset image to default size?

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, uiimageview, uibutton

I am using images in both UIImageViews and UIButtons.  I've been re-sizing them a bit and don't remember what their original sizes were.  Is there an easy way within Interface Builder to "reset" the image back to whatever it's default size is?

Comment: Have you been resizing the image or the imageViews and buttons?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes use apple(command)+equal key with your image view or button selected.